# How to convert BASE64 to URL? Typescript - Angular - Ionic

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, ionic-framework

someone knows how to pass a BASE64 to a URL, I have an application (Ionic) that generates a BASE64 and to share that image I need the URL.

I am using the capacitor plugin to share the image:

```
import { Plugins } from '@capacitor/core';
```

```
const image = 'base64-string........'

async sharedLink(image: any) {
    await Plugins.Share.share({
      url: image
    });
}
```

When I share it from my app, only the base64 string is seen, I need the converted image to come out:

[image: EXAMPLE 1][image: EXAMPLE 2]

Comment: That url simply goes to the `src` attribute of an `img` element, see example on https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_URI_scheme#Examples_of_use . However I do not know how to do that with the framework you use.

Comment: I don't need to show the image in an img tag, I need to be able to share the image, as well as I show in the screenshots that I added

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the following capacitor plugin: https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/social-sharing

First install the plugin.

```
npm install cordova-plugin-x-socialsharing
npm install @ionic-native/social-sharing
ionic cap sync
```

app.module.ts

```
import { SocialSharing } from '@ionic-native/social-sharing/ngx';

providers: [
     SocialSharing
]
```

your-page.page.ts

```
import { SocialSharing } from '@ionic-native/social-sharing/ngx';

constructor(private socialSharing: SocialSharing)

const image = 'base64-string........'

async sharedLink(image: any) {
    this.socialSharing.share(null, null, image, null);
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You can encode/decode to base64 using the `window.btoa` and `window.atob` functions, respectively. Non-primitives need to be serialized into JSON first.

```
const plainData = { hello: "world" };         // Object { hello: "world" }
const jsonData = JSON.stringify(plainData);   // "{\"hello\":\"world\"}"
const base64Data = window.btoa(jsonData);     // "eyJoZWxsbyI6IndvcmxkIn0="
const decodedJson = window.atob(base64Data);  // "{\"hello\":\"world\"}"
const decodedParsedData = 
  JSON.parse("{\"hello\":\"world\"}");        // Object { hello: "world" }
```

Answer (score -1):

There is a encodeURI function supporter by every browsers

var uri = "my test.asp?name=ståle&car=saab";
var res = encodeURI(uri);

But the size of the query string is limited and passing an image that way is not a good practice, prefer a POST method.